# Do I need a webservice or a web api

Tags: android, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an android app which is kinda like a form. How it works currently is that the data the user enters is parsed as json to a php script and stored in a database. I heard that thats not the best way to do it and that i need to use a webservice / web API instead to interface with the server since that is much more secure. My question is, do I really need to use a webservice / API to send the data? If I do, can you direct me to a resourse where I can learn how to create this?

Answer (score 0):

Who says that your web service cannot be written in PHP? There is not much of a difference between a web service and a normal PHP page that reads your JSON data. Just google for something like "php json web service", you'll get a ton of info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a soap service you can access it with [ksoap](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html).

Here is example:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class ChartService {
private static final String GET_USER_ACTION = "http://service.chartengine.core/getUsersFullNameBasedOnSession";
private static final String GET_USER_METHOD_NAME = "getUsersFullNameBasedOnSession";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://service.chartengine.core";
private static final String URL = "http://10.10.10.22:8080/axis2/services/ChartService?wsdl";

private static String name = "";

public static String getUserFullName(){
    if(ECSSecurityService.sessionID.isEmpty())
        return "";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, GET_USER_METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("sessionIDArg", SecurityService.sessionID);
    final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    final HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ht.call(GET_USER_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                name = response.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    int countWait = 5; 
    while (name.isEmpty() && countWait > 0){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
        countWait--;
    }
    return name;
}

}
```

This call has 5sec timeout. Hope it helps.